# Transformation of random variables - what is the region

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Trying to figure out the following problem. Let $X_1\sim g(x_1)$ and $X_2\sim f(x_2)$ indep. random variables ($0<x_i<1\,\forall i$). For example, both $g$ and $f$ could be Beta distributions with different set of parameters. Now, I would like to obtain the distribution of $y=x_1(1-x_2)/[x_2(1-x_1)]$. So, we need to evaluate
$$
P(Y\leq y)=\iint\limits_{R}g(x_1)f(x_2)dx_1dx_2,
$$
where $R=\{(x_1,x_2)|x_1(1-x_2)/[x_2(1-x_1)]\leq y\}$.

I am having problem defining the partition subspace $R$ to evaluate the integral. Thinking of the $(x_1,x_2)$ plane, we have an unit square. I am not sure if this is the right strategy, I started partitioning it into four areas: ($x_1\leq 1/2$ and $x_2\leq 1/2$), ($x_1\geq 1/2$ and $x_2\geq 1/2$), ($x_1\geq 1/2$ and $x_2\leq 1/2$) and ($x_1\leq 1/2$ and $x_2\geq 1/2$). I'd appreciate any comments and suggestions on how to obtain $R$. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If it's doable, you may first try compute the distribution of $x_1 / (1-x_1)$, or some other transformation tricks. But generally, you use the independence for the partition. You choose which variable will be in the middle integral, let it be $x_1$. The integral will be over $\{x_1 : x_1 / (1-x_1) \leq y *x_2/ (1-x_2)\}$, the outer integral over $(0,1)$.